# Automating the build process on TIBCO using Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, tibco-business-works

We are planning to automate the build process on TIBCO environment using Jenkins.

Am new to TIBVO area, Can you please help me or give a walkthrough to achieve this?

Comment: What is your goal? Why you need to build tibco bw projects from Jenkins ?

Comment: Which version you're using? BW5 or BW6?

Comment: BW6, we are looking to automate the build process (Generation of .ear file by taking the code from Subversion).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven plugin for TIBCO BusinessWorks
https://fastconnect.github.io/tibco-factory/bw-maven-plugin/

for building the Tibco BW project from Jenkins

There is a Maven archetype provided called archetype-client-root-project.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.maven \
                    -DarchetypeArtifactId=archetype-client-root-project \
                    -DgroupId=com.company.project \
                    -DartifactId=project-root \
                    -Dversion=1.0.0 \
                    -DclientProjectName=ABC \
                    -DfcFactoryParentVersion=2.4.1 \
                   [-DinteractiveMode=false]
```

please see http://fastconnect.github.io/tibco-factory//configuration.html for configuration instructions.

this plugin is covering build tibco .ear. More interesting question how to deploy .ear project to tibco using Jenkins. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write appManage commands and execute that with the help or ANT Targets.
In Jenkins you just need to specify only one target that is getting called and it will create the build and deploy on different servers.